# Determine command name in vimperator

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, vimperator

I would like to customise vimperator using the .vimperatorrc file.
For now I am doing things like

```
:cmap <C-g> <Esc>
```

so that C-g cancels inputing a command, just as  does. However, I would much prefer bind the key directly to the command. The problem is that I don't know the name of the command that  is mapped to.
Is there a way to see that?
Similarly I would like to map the effect of   or  to <ù> but have trouble finding the name of the command.

For emacs users, the feature I am looking for is something similar to C-h k with the default key bindings.